# Ziggurat matrix doesn't work with "for" and "repeat" loops in R - Why?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix, repeat

I'm a beginner in R. I cannot understand why "for" loops doesn't work in my matrix. I need to build ziggurat in which I enter "n" in function that will have to return a matrix like in the picture.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnjgz.png)
This code works with n is equal to 5, or less than 5. But when it's bigger than 5, "for" loop doens't run through all (1:hunt) number. For example, see the picture below
[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmgca.png)
I tried to use "repeat" loop but it doesn't work too. Where is a mistake in my code?

```
build_ziggurat <- function(n){
h<-1  
hunt <- n-4
if(n==1){
 m<- matrix(1, nrow = 1, ncol = 1)
  } else {
  if(n<5){
  d <- matrix(h, ncol = 2*n-h, nrow=2*n-h)
  d[2:(n+n-2),2:(n+n-2)]<-h+1;d
  d[(n-h):(n+h), (n-h):(n+h)]<-n-h;d
  d[n,n]<-n;d
  print(d)
} else {

  for(i in hunt:1){
    h<-1
      t <- matrix(h, ncol = 2*n-h, nrow=2*n-h)
      t[2:(n+n-2),2:(n+n-2)]<-h+1
      t[(n-h-i):(n+h+i), (n-h-i):(n+h+i)]<-(n-h-i)
      t[(n-h):(n+h),(n-h):(n+h)]<-n-h
      t[n,n]<-n
      return(t)

  }      

}
}
if(n==1) m
}
```

Comment: what you expect to find?Can you explain your logic of ziggurat .

Comment: @M.Hassan In ziggurat I have "n" levels. Every level must contain index number from 1 to "n" where "n" is the top level of ziggurat. In screenshot 2 you can see that there is no "4" in levels. Instead of it I have "3" in two levels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like that?

```
zigguratCreator <- function(n){
  out <- mat.or.vec(nr = (n - 1)*2 + 1, nc = (n - 1)*2 + 1) + 1
  for(i in seq(n - 1)){
    out[seq(i + 1, nrow(out) - i), seq(i + 1, ncol(out) - i)] <- i + 1
  }

  return(out)
}

zigguratCreator(n = 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
zigguratCreator <- function(n){
  size <- 2*n-1
  out <- matrix(nr=size, nc=size)
  for(i in 1:size){
    for (j in 1:size){
      out[i,j] <-min(n-abs(i-n),n-abs(j-n))
    }
  }
  return(out)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. When answering questions, its a good idea to explain how and why your proposed solution solves the question at hand.
More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer